# Substitute original WordPress url by another domain name

Tags: domain

I do have a very basic question, but struggle to understand things.

I do have a Wordpress, host on WorldLite by Planet Hoster. Url is something like "mysite.go.yo".

When I go to a post, url becomes "mysite.go.yo/my-awesome-post".

Now, I simply would like to switch from "mysite.go.yo" to something more sexy, like "mysite.com". I am just talking about the browser url display, purely cosmetic, not actually moving files.
I would also like that links appear as "mysite.com/my-awsome-post" rather than "mysite.go.yo/my-awesome-post" or always "mysite.com".

I do have the domain "mysite.com" with OVH but I clearly struggle to get desired result. Is it possible to achieve expected result when domain name is not host by the WordPress host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, to achieve this result one shall:

1. Create a CNAME redirection from its .com to its .go.yo,
2. Update default DNS Zone from OVH by the one of the PH host,
3. Create an domain name alias on PH,
4. Update WordPress with new url

But things are easier if host & .com are held by the same company.